# How do I have a line of periods till i get to the price?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Here is my li

```
<li>    
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" data="0" class="select_service fl">    
    <div style="margin-left: 5px; width:509px; float:left;    overflow-x: hidden;    overflow-y: hidden;" class="label">Back Office System - Professional........................................................................................................................................</div>
    <small class="rt white">$996.00</small>
</li>
```

I assumed my periods would stop right before the price but they always overlap...any ideas on how to make the periods go to right before the price...

Comment: Can you create a little jsfiddle.net because I'm not understanding your problem...

Comment: ok so here is my http://jsfiddle.net/3YnUG/ and what i want to do is have the dots stop right before the price so there are dots between the price and name

Comment: He basicly wants to do this:  Soup................$4.50

Answer (score 2):

Add `white-space:pre;` to the `.label` element, so that the line does not get wrapped any more.

Because the label has a fixed width, you also have to add a fixed width to the parent (container). Otherwise, the `<small>` element will not stay at the same line as `.label`, because it doesn't fit (in smaller viewports).

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L8gyn/

Relevant code:

```
<div style="white-space: pre;
            margin-left: 5px;
            width:509px;
            float:left;
            overflow: hidden;" class="label">
```

Instead of hard-coding the dot characters, you can also use other methods, such as `border` or `<fieldset>` to display dots.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS background and a `:before` pseudo-element to add the dots. Something similar to http://jsfiddle.net/gGdMd/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method.  I don't think it's particularly elegant but it seems to do what you are asking for. http://jsfiddle.net/V5tVx/

The basic method is to position the dots in the background and then use absolute positioning to put the name and price on the left and right sides.  I've changed the HTML slightly to make this possible.

HTML:

```
<ul id="pricelist">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span class="linefiller">
            ...............................................................................................................................
        </span>
        <span class="itemname">Back office system</span>
        <span class="itemprice">$996.00</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span class="linefiller">
            ...............................................................................................................................
        </span>
        <span class="itemname">Filing cabinet</span>
        <span class="itemprice">$100.00</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#pricelist {
    width:300px;
    margin:auto;
}

#pricelist > li {
    position:relative; /* required so that absolute positioning works later */
}

.itemname {
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:20px; /* leave space for the checkbox */
    top:0px;
    background-color:white; /* so that we don't see dots underneath */
}

.itemprice {
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px; /* right-aligned */
    top:0px;
    background-color:white; /* so that we don't see dots underneath */
}

.linefiller {
    display:block;
    max-width:280px; /* should be 20px less than the list width */
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    left:20px; /* leave space for the checkbox */
    top:0px;
}
```